# I want to put my data in chartjs-plugin-streaming

Tags: chart.js

```
type: 'realtime',
    realtime: {
      duration: 20000,
      refresh: 2000,
      delay: 2000,
      pause: false,
      ttl: undefined,
      onRefresh: onRefresh

function onRefresh(chart: any) {
chart.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset: any) {
dataset.data.push({
  x: Date.now(),
  y: +this.selectedSensor.sensor_val
  // y: undefined
});
});
chart.update();
}
```

I changed the string data to number and put it in.

```
y: +this.selectedSensor.sensor_val
```

And I've also used a shape-shifting method, but no data appears on the graph.

Comment: console error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedSensor' of undefined
    at indoor-model-view.component.ts:429

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using `'use strict'`? In strict mode, the value of `this` remains as `undefined`, as explained in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context. If `selectedSensor` is defined as a global variable, use the global object (`window` in a browser) instead of `this`.